# WPLANG option not available in localhost

Tags: multisite, localization

In my website which is multi-site, sub-directory, XAMPP based and hosted in local machine "WPLANG" option is not available for any site. But its available in azure based wordpress. Is there anything special I need to do, to make it available in my local machine.
I'm creating a theme which should be available in 5 languages. And I would need this WPLANG option to set different locale code for different sites.

Comment: what does it mean "option is not available", and why do you think it should be otherwise?

Comment: If we go to settings for each site through MySites->Network Admin-> Sites, there we have options to enter locale codes under WPLANG. That option is not available in localhost.

Comment: again, what do you mean "not available"? is it not displayed, and if so, so what?, what is it that you try to do and can't? It is very unlikely that the difference has anything to do with running multisite on localhost. Right now to answer the question someone will need to install multisite on localhost, something that is not very likely that will be done just to answer it. You need full details so people might be able to spot the problem from reading the question.problem